# Learn computer architecture and organisation via an oversimplified machine

Tags: computer-architecture, simulation, instruction-set

I wish to learn CO&A (computer organisation and architecture) from scratch via some toy system and its simulator. I found the following resource: [Toy Machine](https://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/62toy/) developed at Princeton University.

**Toy Machine**, however, is quite old and although a good starting point, doesn't quite capture some recent logic.

So the question is, is there an academic modern architecture along with a simulator for this purpose?

Comment: Can you be explicit about "doesn't quite capture some recent logic" ? What are you referring to ?

Comment: I was merely quoting the homepage of Toy: _TOY is an imaginary machine (created at Princeton) that is very similar to ancient computers._. However, what we can note is that it is 16 bit and doesn't talk about any vectors.

Comment: I just wanted to ask if there is any other similar academic architecture that is of more recent design!

Comment: You are wrong to think that more recent implies new logic. In particular, the word size is irrelevant (and vectors bring nothing new).

Comment: Also note that the Toy Machine's architecture is of the von Neumann type, and nothing better has been (needs to be) invented.